# How do I Unstick a Fixture Mounted to Bathroom Tile

Tags: bathroom, tile, adhesive

Let's say, hypothetically, that I bought one of those lighted, fogless mirrors [like this](https://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/store/product/haven-9-inch-x-7-inch-rectangular-fogless-led-shaving-mirror-in-white/5516905) which stick to the tile in your shower and chose a really bad location to mount it. **How do I get it off?** I thought it would pull off fairly easily, but it feels too stuck and I will just break it by pulling.

Also, if you all have any good recommendations for shower stall mirrors, I'd like to hear them, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dental floss (bathroom handy) or fishing line. Wrap it around a couple of handles (toothbrushes also seem handy in a bathroom) and saw the thing free of the wall.

Comment: I did that. It worked surprisingly easy. But now there's a lot of residue. How do I get that off?

Comment: We could stay bathroom centric and use toothpaste, but you might get it off faster with shortening or vegetable oil from the kitchen. That's a guess, not a guarantee, but often works - depends on the adhesive residue. Shampoo or conditioner might also work? Or rubbing alcohol...

Comment: I had some Goof Off. Sprayed that on and was able to slowly peel it off using my fingernail (still the best cleaning tool ever created). All done.